# Understanding half first cousin DNA results when no match?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-first-cousins

We have strong reason to believe we know who my aunt's half first cousin is. However, he is not matching her with autosomnal dna test on ancestry.

Its fair to say ok forget it but there are so many things that point that way.

Is it possible that its just not showing up?

He would be my half first cousin once removed.

Might he show up with me if i took a test?

Also it's his grandfather that is thought to be my dad's and aunt's grandfather. Obviously different grandmothers.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the DNA evidence rather than family stories or circumstantial evidence. Lack of a DNA match between two people is considered excellent evidence that they cannot be 2nd cousins or any closer relationship. (1/2 first cousin is closer than 2nd cousin).

In the [Shared Centimorgan](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/08/26/august-2017-update-to-the-shared-cm-project/) project, genetic genealogist Blaine Bettinger collected over 25,000 matches and relationships. I believe that it is a true statement that no verified case of 2nd cousins or closer without a DNA match has ever been observed.